# Print only the even numbers in nested lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop

This is what I have:

```py
mylist1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]   

for i in mylist1:
    if i[0] % 2 == 0:
        print(i[0])
    if i[1] % 2 == 0:
        print(i[1])
    if i[2] % 2 == 0:
        print(i[2])
```

Is there a shorter way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a flat list out of list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists) ... and [Flattening a shallow list in Python (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a nested loop try this.

```
mylist1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]   

for i in mylist1:
    for j in i:
        if j % 2 == 0:
            print(j)
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension?

```
print('\n'.join(str(i) for sublist in mylist1 for i in sublist if i % 2 == 0))
```

Less hardcore list comprehension?

```
for sublist in mylist1:
    print('\n'.join(i for i in sublist if i % 2 == 0))
```

For loop?

```
for sublist in mylist1:
    for i in sublist:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter with itertools' [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain
mylist1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]   

print(list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, chain.from_iterable(mylist1))))

# [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: That's elegant.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the format is going to be a list of lists, I suppose you could just use nested for loops

```py
mylist1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]  
for x in mylist1:
    for y in x:
        if y%2 == 0:
            print(y)
```

Unless you're asking it to be quicker in terms of CPU time in which case I would probably use numpy. Keep experimenting bud!

Comment: Damn, looks like I was beat

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass `*param` to `chain` :

```
from itertools import chain
[i for i in chain(*mylist1) if i % 2 == 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option, a one-liner that uses no imports:

```
print(*[val for lst in mylist1 for val in filter(lambda x: x & 1 == 0, lst)])
```

Or if having them on separate lines is important:

```
print(*[val for lst in mylist1 for val in filter(lambda x: x & 1 == 0, lst)], sep = "\n")
```